# Strange gaps in DDMS trace

Tags: android, android-ndk, ddms, android-traceview

I am analysing the profile information using the DDMS trace view. I have notice that many of my slower functions appear to have strange gaps in the middle of them (see image)... its as if they decided to take a rest half way through and start up again. The profiling data was gathered using "trace based profiling" (as opposed to sample-based) so it should be the case that no function calls are missed. In the text info below, you can see that it says that 100% of the time is taken by "self" so the gap can not be explained by a call to some other function. If I click on the block of colour representing the function then the trace view joins up the two ends of the function with a bar over the top but I don't know what this means.

I am testing all this on an xperia Z phone which has a quad core processor.

[image]

Comment: Is your method uses the threads or sleep?

Comment: I don't call sleep or spawn other threads directly myself. But I guess it is possible that some OS functions I call do.

Comment: is it possible to show code?

Answer (score 0):

Like it is already mentioned in the Trace, the space seems to be taken by the Context Switch.
That doesn't seem to be included in the CPU time, but you can look it up in the real time section.

In my experience, the strange empty spaces are usually Context switches in the CPU level, many a times including BinderProxy.Transact calls.